# Search between two dates in access database using sql

Tags: vb.net, search

This is my code for search in access database 2010. My problem is that when I search between two datetimepicker the result is wrong in datagridview, I mean when I search from specific records between May and June it shows me records also from February.

```
Private Sub Search_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty

    Dim bookdetials As New frmContactDetails

    Try
        'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        sSQL = "SELECT contact_id, first_name , birth_date, book_num, send_from, no_answer, no_answer_by, rec, book_answer_name, book_answer_num, send_date, send_to, project_name FROM tblAddressBook"

        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            sSQL = sSQL & " where project_name like '%" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "%' " & _
        " AND birth_date between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'"
        End If

        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)

        Me.dtgResult.DataSource = dt
        Label4.Text = dt.Rows.Count

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Log your sql statement and add that to your question (if you don't immediately see the answer).

Comment: If you used Command Parameter objects they wouldnt convert dates to text like your code does

Comment: so what should I do in that case ?

Comment: mccainz how can I get log for my sql statement ?

Answer (score 0):

datepicker text should be converted to datetime format in sql

Comment: I converted and still the same problem DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was too silly but it worked
use text instead of datetime in the db
make sure the datetimepicker enters "short format" data